# SQL Data cleaning

Tags: sql, string, sql-update, presto, amazon-athena

I have a data set where I am trying to clean data. I want to remove the ** from email-address and phone_number and have just numbers in the phone_number column. how can i do it.

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using: sql-server, oracle, postgresql...? Also, please show us the result that you want for this sample data (as tabular text rather than images). Finally, what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using string functions:

```
update mytable 
set email        = replace(email, '**', ''), 
    phone_number = regexp_replace(phone_number, '\\D', '')
```

This removes `'**'` from `email`, and all non-digit characters from `phone_number`.